# Force function documentation in Doxygen for documenting JavaScript API

Tags: warnings, doxygen

I use Doxygen for documenting the JavaScript API of my C++ (Qt) project. The idea is to write one specific documentation for the JavaScript interfaces, and one for the C++ classes us usual. 
One example (datasource.dox) looks like this:

```
\addtogroup JavaScriptAPI
@{
...
\class DataSource
\brief DataSource is the .... some doc goes here ....

\section formats Supported formats
....

\fn isOpen()
\brief returns true if the data source is currently open...
...
@}
```

The generated help looks nice w.r.t. the class description (or 'object'-description), but the function documentation (isOpen(), ...) is missing. Doxygen creates warning messages like:
Warning: documented function `bool isOpen' was not declared or defined.

The question, now: can I somehow force doxygen to use my \fn-d function descriptions? It would be nice, if doxygen created all those member indices for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches for using doxygen with Javascript are listed here http://www.doxygen.org/helpers.html
(look for JavaScript)